# Change date format in a list

Tags: r, list, date

I would like to change the date format in my list, which is composed by 190 dataframes.

Here part of the last dataframe in the list:

```
[[190]]
           Date   Weight    Code
8   01 Jul 1852   250.082   54002
9   11 Nov 1852   357.547   54002
10  24 Mar 1867   269.702   54002
11  21 Jul 1875   303.433   54002
[....]
```

As you can see my date format is "%d %b %Y" but I want to change it into"%d-%m-%Y".

I tried to use a loop within lapply but it didn't work.

I need also to convert the Date columns into Date format (now they are Factor).

My output should be:

```
[[190]]
           Date   Weight    Code
8    1852-07-01   250.082   54002
9    1852-11-11   357.547   54002
10   1867-03-24   269.702   54002
11   1875-07-21   303.433   54002
[....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, transform, Date = as.Date(Date, "%d %b %Y"))
```

Once we convert to `Date` class, it is easier to convert to any other `format`

```
lapply(lst1, transform, Date = format(Date, "%d-%m-%Y"))
```